# Angular 2+ and Laravel - Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel, angular

For post request from Angular to Laravel I am getting error(Internal Server Error). But it successfully works in Postman.

api.php

```
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    Route::post('/addHouse', [
        'uses' => 'HouseController@postHouse'
    ]);
```

HouseController.php

```
    public function postHouse(Request $request)
{
    $house=new House();
    $house->houseName=$request->input('houseName');
    $house->type=$request->input('type');
    $house->for=$request->input('for');
    $house->address=$request->input('address');
    $house->price=$request->input('price');
    $house->description=$request->input('description');
    $house->bedrooms=$request->input('bedrooms');
    $house->bathrooms=$request->input('bathrooms');
    $house->area=$request->input('area');
    $house->save();
    return response()->json([
        'house'=>$house
    ],201);
}
```

Cors.php(Middleware)

```
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         return $next($request)
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','Get, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, Authorization');
     }
```

In Angular house.service.ts

```
    addHouse(content)  {
        console.log(content);
        const body = JSON.stringify({
        content: content
    });
    const headers = new Headers({
       'Content-Type':'application/json'
    });
   return this._http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/addHouse', body, {
       headers: headers
   });
  }
```

My error -> **POST http://localhost:8000/api/addHouse 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You probably need to supply csrf token in http header

Comment: Do you mean Cors middleware? I am giving it.

Comment: I edited. Please give me whole cors middleware code if you find it wrong.

Comment: @MuhammadHussain can you post response form network tab?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing addHouse function. Thanks everyone..

```
    addHouse(data) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append (
           'Content-type','application/json'
        );
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/addHouse', JSON.stringify(data), {
                   headers:headers
                  }).map(res => res.json());
    }
```